# How to make sure my while loop does not break my condition?

Tags: javascript, while-loop

I'm practicing a simple while loop. Buy a phone for the cost of 200 only until my bank account hits 500, but because it buys the phone first it only knows you dropped below 500 after it buys the phone.

In my code, it's buying until it takes the bankaccountmoney variable to 400:

```js
var bankaccountmoney = 2000;
var phonesbought = 0;
var phonecost = 200;

while (bankaccountmoney > 500) {
  phonesbought = phonesbought + 1;
  bankaccountmoney = bankaccountmoney - phonecost;
  console.log("money: " + bankaccountmoney + " phonesbought: " + phonesbought);
}
```

Comment: `while (bankaccountmoney > phonecost) {` might help :)

Comment: so either subtract the cost it from the amount or add it to the 500

Comment: Well, starting from 2000 and subtracting multiples of 200 will never hit 500.  Do you instead want to prevent it from dropping below 500?

Comment: `while(bankaccountmoney > 500 + phonecost)`

Comment: `while(bankaccountmoney >= 500 + phonecost)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while (bankaccountmoney - phonecost >= 500) {
...
}
```

Comment: `>=` i think.. restricting below 500, can also be == 500

Comment: Yeah, that's probably what OP wanted. Fixed the answer, thanks.

Comment: Dang that works! I wouldn't have thought of that. So here it's subtracting the phone cost before it checks if it's greater than 500.

Comment: You can say it tries to predict the outcome of potential operation, just like you would do this in real life: "Given my current account balance and the phone cost, can I buy it and still be able to pay the bills next month?"

Answer (score 1):

Another approach, using a couple of utility functions. I don't like doing math in `while` predicates. Way too easy to misread.

```js
const phoneCost = 200;
const targetSavings = 500;
    
// Can I afford to buy something, given target savings, purchase price,
// and current funds?
const canAffordPurchase = target => purchase => funds => 
       (funds - purchase >= target);
    
// Can I afford to buy this phone in particular?
const canAffordPhone = canAffordPurchase(targetSavings)(phoneCost);
    
let availableFunds = 2000;
let phonesBought = 0;
    
// Buy as many phones as I can afford.
while(canAffordPhone(availableFunds)) {
  phonesBought += 1;
  availableFunds -= phoneCost;
  console.log(`money: ` + availableFunds + " phonesBought: " + phonesBought);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var bankaccountmoney = 2000;
var phonesbought = 0;
var phonecost = 200;

while (bankaccountmoney >= (500 + phonecost)) {
  phonesbought++;
  bankaccountmoney -= phonecost;
  console.log("money left: " + bankaccountmoney + " phonesbought: " + phonesbought);
}
```

and here's a snippet if you instead have 100 as phone cost

```js
var bankaccountmoney = 2000;
var phonesbought = 0;
var phonecost = 100;

while (bankaccountmoney >= (500 + phonecost)) {
  phonesbought++;
  bankaccountmoney -= phonecost;
  console.log("money left: " + bankaccountmoney + " phonesbought: " + phonesbought);
}
```